# Invoke arithmetic operator dynamically

Tags: powershell, reflection, operator-keyword

Powershell has arithmetic operators like addition (+), substraction (-) and bitwise and (-band). I'm making a simple calculator program, and I want to dynamically perform arithmetic calculations based on the user input, without needing to write a lot of if-else statements. Is there a way to dynamically invoke powershell operators? E.g. if $method=="plus" do "6+6".

I know there is Invoke-Expression, but that doesn't really operate on the operator alone (you also need to supply the operands in the expression string). Is there some way to define the operator as a variable? E.g. $method="-band", $result=6 $method 6;

Comment: the only thing i can think of is to use a `switch` structure to decide what to do. that doesn't sound very efficient, tho. [*blush*]

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this way

```
$no1 = 10 ; $no2 = 5 ; # your inputs

function plus($one , $two)  # plus operation method
{
    $ans = $no1 + $no2 ;
    Write-Output $ans

}

function minus($one , $two) # minus operation method
{
    $ans = $no1 - $no2 ;
    Write-Output $ans
}


$method = "plus" # dyn. method name
& "$method" 10 5 # Call method with param

$method = "minus" ; # dyn. method name
& "$method" 10 5    # Call method with param
```

Comment: Output will be :
15
5